# Is it possible to reuse the DOM of flatpickr pane for multiple instances?

Tags: javascript, flatpickr

We're using [flatpickr](https://github.com/flatpickr/flatpickr) to provide a uniform interface to edit dates. In one instance there's a table with many (hundreds) of rows, each row has a date input where we use flatpickr.

Given that only one flatpickr will be opened at a time, is it possible to avoid the creation of hundreds of hidden panes in the DOM, and instead use a single one for all of them?

[image: example of the dom created for each instance]

Answer (score 2):

So we had a similar issue in an AngularJS application. The workaround that we found was to add a FocusHandler to the input field, create the flatpickr instance inside that handler, and then call `.open()` on the instance.

```
handleFocus = () => {
  const config = {...}
  this.flatpickrInstance = flatpickr(this.input, config);
  this.flatpickrInstance.open();
};
```

To clean up we also added a BlurHandler to the input field to call `.destroy()` on the saved flatpickr instance. The only issue here is that `.destroy()` will clear the value of the input field so we needed to set the value immediately after calling destroy like this:

```
handleBlur = () => {
  const val = this.flatpickrInstance.input.value;
  this.flatpickrInstance.destroy();
  this.input.value = val
};
```